# Select minimum shared common data

Tags: sql, sqlite

Title might be a bit off, but I'll try to explain.

My example data looks like this:

```
door1 | key1
door1 | key2
door2 | key1
door2 | key2
door2 | key3
door3 | key1
door3 | key3
door4 | key2
```

Id like to select the **least amount** of keys needed to open all doors. In this case the output would be key1 for door1, door2 and door3, and key2 for door4.

Output:

```
key1
key2
```

I solved this programmatically but I feel as there should be a way to whip up a select to have the DB do this for me.

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ca68e)

Comment: it also true for `key2` and `key3`

Comment: I'd love to be proved wrong, but I guess it is practically impossible to solve the general problem in SQL. It is basically the [set cover optimization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) which is shown to be NP-hard. If you have solved this programmatically then you may have won a Nobel prize.

Comment: And a bit less flippantly... even implementing a SQL solution that works for very small data sets would be very hard. But honestly, I'd love to see someone with more time have a go.

Comment: [Not sure, if it is correct, and it definitely doesn't work in case there can be multiple combinations in the result with the same number of keys](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ca68e/5)

Comment: @JohnRees NP-hard just means that it's going to be slow, but checking all 2^N possible sets is easy to implement (outside of SQL).

Comment: @CL. I agree that NP-hard just means it's (extremely) slow for large data sets, but I think that even a brute force SQL implementation is tricky. Having said that, I am trying to make one. Just couldn't resist :-)

Comment: Duplicate of [Minimal number of groups necessary to cover user/product permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25334417/11654), but that one does not have a real answer.

Comment: @JohnRees In [SQL for Smarties](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0123820227), Celko uses a CTE with N columns to generate the 2^N subsets. This works for known N, but is apparently not possible for arbitrary N.

Comment: can u use a loop in sql or u just want a select?

Comment: I was aiming just for a plain select. The way it works now is that i generate a top list of keys (by count) and then match up the doors with keys using the top list until i run out of doors to match. My data is under 2k rows in all cases and it goes fast enough. The fiddle potashin posted works with the data-set, I'll try plugging it in the program later to see how it goes. In the above case any one of the answers is good, I don't need both.

Comment: How many keys does it need to handle? And does it have to be SQLite?

Comment: @Dr.Spam: let me know, if the answer suits you, I'll post an answer.

Comment: I quickly slapped it into the program and it died. My quickly hacked junk way executes in 11ms, and the same sample in a select goes on for 19538ms. But the result is the same so i guess what i need can be done with a select statement, only it's not really the best path to take.

Comment: @JohnRees: It should be SQLite. I think the largest set of "door-key" rows is about 1800, about 186 distinct doors and 44 distinct keys (real data is not doors-keys, but the gist of it stays the same).
(I wasn't fast enough to edit the prev comment to include this info)

Comment: I'd be really interested in your code solution. Even returning in 11ms for 44 keys is impressive. Do you start searching with a steadily increasing number of keys so that you can stop as soon as you find a set that opens all doors?

Comment: After reading your implementation notes(in your comment above I can see your approach is to pick what seems to be the next best key at each step.  This is OK since it will certainly come up with a reasonable solution, but it will sometimes choose too many keys.  For instance, using the data in [this SQLFidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/ae3e9/1)  I think your algorithm will choose keys k1,k2,k3,k4 but the best solution uses k5,k6,k7.  It depends whether it is vital that your algorithm always chooses the best set of keys, or whether a reasonable set is good enough.

Comment: @potashin Your implementation is really elegant.  In English, I think it is: _For each door, choose the key that unlocks that door and unlocks the most doors.  Combine all chosen keys into a set._  I agree it will find a reasonable solution, but it will fail to find the best solution for similar reasons as I gave on my previous comment.  See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/ae3e9/3).  BTW I love this problem, and I am just pointing out that finding the guaranteed best solution is hard.

Comment: @JohnRees: That SQLFiddle won't load for me. A reasonable set is good enough, i need a manageable minimal set of roles to access all the parts of various applications on the intranet. What i hacked up works decently :) My implementation is a bit like this (warning, terrible pseudo code ahead):
get list of doors;
make a dictionary door -> key;
get list of keys ordered by number occurence;


while(!dictionaryComplete){
 select door from tbl where key = <nextTopKey>;
 matchDictionaryWithKeys;
}
edit: pseudo code is barely readable smacked in one line :/

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain your solution.  Since you don't have to have the absolute smallest set of keys, your approach seems good. At least you definitely get a result in a short time, rather than waiting for 2^N steps to find the best answer. Just for completeness, I converted two fiddles from SQL.js to WebSQL so they should work for you. A [simple one](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/53dd9/1) and a [surprising one](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/69123f/1)

Comment: I made a small program to handle this door->key situation and with a small amount of rows the SQL way is a bit slower (1ms on the average with 14 rows from the second example) and quite slower with 574 rows (12ms vs 39429ms that goes down to 160ms with indexes). And it outputs the same results as the query does. It's an interesting problem, the solution i have is Good Enough™ for now :) Thank you all for your input!